# Change Font Family in Vaadin-Core 24.3.5

Tags: fonts, vaadin

I am new to Vaadin.
I created a Project through vaadin start.
I chose Chewy font, but the font I had was nothing close to it, so I tried to change it through the files:

- theme.json
- Application.java (@NpmPackage)
- style.css

I also `npm -i` every new @fontsource I am experimenting with.
So far the font won't change, so I am guessing I am doing something wrong.
Are the fonts available for vaadin-core?

Thank you